# Initialize a vector with size beforehand

Tags: arrays, string, vector

The code below shows segmentation fault. But as soon as I replace `vector<int> s;` with `vector<int> s(n)` the code runs fine.
Why does it happen like this and does it destroys the very purpose of a vector where we have to input size beforehand?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    long int n,i,count=0,sum=0;
    cin>>n;
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    vector<int> s1;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {    
        if(s[i]=='U')
           s1[i]=1;
        else
        s1[i]=-1;
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        sum+=s1[i];
        if((sum==0)&&(s1[i]!=(-1)))
            count++;
    } 

     cout<<count;       


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when you don't specify a size, it is initialized with no elements.

You can't set an element if there are none.

In your first for loop:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{    
    if(s[i]=='U')
        s1[i]=1;
    else
        s1[i]=-1;
}
```

Change it to use `push_back` to add new elements to the vector.

Note that if you are modifying already-existing elements you can do it as normal.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{    
    if (s[i]=='U')
        s1.push_back(1);
    else
        s1.push_back(-1);
}
```

This behavoir is like JavaScript's arrays, or Python's lists.